# Issue with awk command inside while loop

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a problem with this awk command because after the first iteration of the while loop, the information is written in the same line as the first iteration instead of written in the row where the value is found.

```
while read list
do
    awk -v M="$Variable" -v R="Fail" -v J="Sorry, but this fail" -v K="N/A"  '
        BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","}
        $1==M {$14=R; $21=J; $22=K; print}
        $1 != M ' file.csv > file2.csv
done < list.csv
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Your code clearly overwrites `file2.csv` as many times as there are lines in `list.csv` but you have not explained why it's doing this, or how the files are related. Do you just want to loop over lines in `file.csv`? Then the `while` loop is superfluous. Does `list.csv` contain names of files to process? Then the loop should use the value in `$list` for something, such as the input file name for Awk.

Comment: This problem may be easier to understand (and solve) if you gave sample of your input. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of `file.csv > file2.csv` you'll need `file.csv >> file2.csv`. The `>` will overwrite `file2.csv`, and the `>>` will append to it.

Comment: the issue is if i do that i have so much information duplicated in the file2.csv that i dont wish, because it add me other row, and i need overwrite the information , no adds more information

Comment: If i do (file.csv >> file2.csv) i will have the file2.csv with two lines duplicated<br/>For example in this file :<br/>column1   column14      column21                       column22<br/>usb 1          fail               Sorry but this fail             N/A                <br/>usb2<br/>usb 1          fail               Sorry but this fail             N/A